# Google FCM in PHP showing error for IOS push notification but working on Android

Tags: php, ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

Google FCM in PHP showing error for IOS push notification but working on Android.

Error Response:

```
{
    "multicast_id": 2868006956446234402,
    "success": 0,
    "failure": 1,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "error": "InvalidParameters: AppleDeliveryError:BAD_REQUEST_TOPIC_DISALLOWED"
        }
    ]
}
```

Please Help! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved!

We setup push notification services again on developer.apple.com and updated API_ACCESS_KEY in PHP code.